# python Packaging and distributing projects

Tags: python

I want to package the python project, but when I package the project and the python files in the project need to use data files, ‘FileNotFoundError’ appears. The following figure is my project structure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQoNq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFJoy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkhyz.png)

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# To use a consistent encoding
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()


setup(
    name='NERChinese',
    version='0.0.6',

    description='基于BiLSTM-CRF的字级别中文命名实体识别模型',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',

    # The project's main homepage.
    url='https://github.com/cswangjiawei/Chinese-NER',

    # Author details
    # author='wangjiawei',
    # author_email='cswangjiawei@163.com',

    # Choose your license
    # license='MIT',

    # What does your project relate to?
    keywords='Named-entity recognition using neural networks',

    # You can just specify the packages manually here if your project is
    # simple. Or you can use find_packages().
    packages=find_packages(),

    zip_safe=False,
    package_data={
    'NERChinese': ['data/*'],
},
)
```

‘FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/msra_train.txt'’ appears when 'with open (train path,' R ', encoding ='utf-8') as F1: 'in utils.py file is run. How should I package data files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't specify the correct path when you open it, you can try instead:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/msra_train.txt'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as F1:
```

This way, it is relative to the module of your package, not relative to where you are calling it.

If it does not work, can you check if you have your data in site-packages?